# Django LDAPS TLS started failing with error SERVER_DOWN

Tags: python, django, ldap

Today we had the pleasure of LDAPS failing in a Django application.

Our Pip requirements includes:

```
python-ldap==3.3.1
django-auth-ldap==3.0.0
```

Our Django settings file includes:

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldaps://ldaps.server.net.au:636"

AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS = {
    ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL: 1,
    ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: 0,
    ldap.OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT: 5.0,
    ldap.OPT_TIMEOUT: 5.0,
}
```

The vague error we're seeing is:

```
Caught LDAPError while authenticating sighmon: SERVER_DOWN({'result': -1, 'desc': "Can't contact LDAP server", 'errno': 115, 'ctrls': [], 'info': '(unknown error code)'},)
```

It had been working nicely for ~2 years prior to today.

We tried pinning `django-auth-ldap` to various older versions, but all failed in the same way.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to firstly get debug output by setting options using `AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS` instead of `AUTH_LDAP_CONNECTION_OPTIONS`.

This then gave the more useful error: `TLS: peer cert untrusted or revoked (0x42).`

We confirmed that `LDAP` without the **S** authenticated okay, so kept digging into TLS issues.

We tested connecting to the LDAPS server with: `telnet ldaps.server.net.au:636` and that happily connected. So it seemed that our LDAPS server was happy.

We checked the certs with: `openssl s_client -showcerts -verify 5 -connect ldaps.server.net.au:636 < /dev/null`

Everything seemed okay, so we kept looking into LDAP options...

This option fixed things for us: `ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT: ldap.OPT_X_TLS_ALLOW` so our full options ended up being:

```
AUTH_LDAP_GLOBAL_OPTIONS = {
    ldap.OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL: 1,
    ldap.OPT_REFERRALS: 0,
    ldap.OPT_NETWORK_TIMEOUT: 5.0,
    ldap.OPT_TIMEOUT: 5.0,
    ldap.OPT_X_TLS_REQUIRE_CERT: ldap.OPT_X_TLS_ALLOW,
}
```

See the open issue with this and other solutions: https://github.com/django-auth-ldap/django-auth-ldap/issues/198

**Next step**: work out what's wrong with our cert bundle